# OpenCL SPIR binary build is very slow on Intel Skylake GPU

Tags: opencl, spir

I've have a number of OpenCL kernels that are compiled into `SPIR` binaries. I understand that:

> Additional time is required to build a program from a SPIR binary as opposed to building a program from an Intermediate Binary, since additional translation and optimization steps are involved.

See: [Using SPIR for fun and profit with Intel® OpenCL™ Code Builder](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-spir-for-fun-and-profit-with-intel-opencl-code-builder)

However, building the `SPIR` kernels on an Intel Skylake i7 GPU takes almost a minute!
Is this a `SPIR` specific issue? Would `SPIR-V` be any faster?

Comment: How long does the online (non-SPIR) compiler take by comparison? How big is your kernel? Seems excessive to me; our online kernels only take seconds at most. But then again, FPGA OpenCL compiles can take hours or days when fully optimized.

Comment: @Dithermaster loading the `IR` format kernel files took 82mS on the first load and 7mS on subsequent loads. Clearly the processor/GPU was caching the kernels after the first load. There are two kernel files: the simple `SPIR` kernel file loads in under 650mS, the complex one takes over 55 seconds. The complex kernel file has 11 kernels, 650 lines approx and takes just over a minute to compile using the latest version of Code Builder in MSVC 2017.

Comment: Wow, even 55 seconds to load the IR? And over a minute to compile to IR?
 Seems odd. Perhaps break it out into multiple programs (instead of one program with 11 kernels)?

Comment: @Dithermaster I think that you misread some of the numbers, it only took 82mS to load the IR, it was over 55 seconds for the SPIR. The IR load time is not a problem, I would prefer to load SPIR format for portability, but not with that overhead! My concern is that SPIR-V format may be just as slow, but my system does not support it. Unfortunately, I can't split the program further since the kernels have a lot of code in common.

Comment: What are you calling IR? I was thinking of SPIR as the IR. Do you mean to load the binary that you saved from a prior compile? In any case, minute long compiles seem like a bug. I wonder, since this is also on Intel, if this other topic is related (do you use short-circuit conditionals?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733155/opencl-files-fail-to-compile-on-os-x

Comment: @Dithermaster Intel Code-Builder gives binary files `ir` extensions; SPIR and SPIR-V  files have `spir` and `spirv`extensions respectively. The kernel code uses shot circuit conditionals, it also uses many booleans prior the conditionals as per you answer. I changed the remaining kernel conditionals to use booleans, but it had no effect...